# ListView ... raised event Sorting which wasn't handled

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, listview

I'm trying to understand how the Sort options work with the ListView object in ASP.net 4.5.  I've read the MSDN links and several of the posts here on SO, but I must be missing something because I keep receiving the error above.

If I've interpreted the documentation correctly, I am supposed to be able to trigger a sort multiple ways:

1. via a command button with CommandName="Sort"
2. using an OnClick event on an object
3. adding `OnSorting='some_sort_function'` to the properties of the ListView object.

I can't seem to get any of them to work.

I have the following:

.ASPX

```
<asp:ListView ID="courseListView" runat="server">
...
<asp:LinkButton ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Title" 
                OnClick="courseListView_Sorting" >
</asp:LinkButton>
```

ASPX.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        SqlDataSource orc = new SqlDataSource();
        orc.ProviderName = "System.Data.OracleClient";
        orc.ConnectionString = OracleConnectStr;
        orc.SelectCommand = "select display_title as title from ...";
        courseListView.DataSource = orc; 
        courseListView.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void courseListView_Sorting(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    courseListView.Sort("display_title", SortDirection.Ascending);
}
```

All of the posts seem say you have to create a handler for the Sort event, but isn't that what my `courseListView_Sorting()` is?

Comment: when you set a breakpoint in the `Page_Load` event after clicking on the LinkButton.. does it hit the page load event if so ..what is the value of `IsPostBack` is it false or true..?

Comment: The value of IsPostBack is true.

Comment: Okay, so after moving my datasource information from the code behind to .aspx page it works fine.  Is it not possible to do sorting when the code behind assigns the datasource?  What am I missing here?